# Cursor change on hover

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to change the cursor on hover when mouse cursor hovers over a table. The view here is written in ruby-rails. I tried simply adding

```
.custom > table:hover·
{
    cursor: wait;
}
```

adding the above to custom.css.scss

And then I added the below code to my view

```
<table class="nav nav-tabs custom">
```

This does not seem to work.
I know the css code has to be within some block but I am not sure of the exact way of going about it especially within ruby on rails. Any way to correct what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

Thanks for the suggestions.

I tried this

```
table.custom:hover{
    cursor:wait;
}
```

although this works in the table header it does not work for the part where the data within the table is being rendered:

```
  <table style="display:none" class="nav nav-tabs custom">
      <%= render ClassName.new, :index => 'N_TYPE' %>
  </table>
```

And rendering columns similar to this

```
<td><%= label_tag :p_type, p_type.p_type %></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.custom > table:hover·
{
    cursor: wait;
}
```

What your CSS does is it looks for a children *table* inside a selector with class *.custom*. So it wont work for your HTML.

The proper way is

```
table.custom:hover{
    cursor:wait;
}
```

which looks for a table with the class name *.custom* and applies CSS

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3lackRos3/f04uuqfb/)

Comment: do I need to add it within some `class="nav nav-tabs custom"' block? I mean we how will HTML know that this is the class we are referring to

Comment: I mean can I simply append the code snippet anywere in the custom file and expect it to work but just adding the class="nav nav-tabs custom" to the table ? Well I did try it for some reason its not working.

Comment: Is your table having the class 'custom'?. Or can u create a fiddle with the code you have?

Comment: Mine is a huge code and your suggestion works fine when I apply it to the header but when I try to do for the <table> rendering code here </table> this does not work. I will edit the question above.

Comment: Can u post the rendered html?

Comment: I will try to do that in a readable way. But it seems for some reason, the mouse pointer is already a ":pointer" over the labels that are present in the redered HTML (without adding the new snippet for wait). I wonder if thats the problem and why that would happen.

Answer (score 2):

In your style you have made use of the child combinator ">". Child combinator is used to apply CSS to child elements of the selected element.
For eg.
HTML:

```
 <ul>
   <li>First</li>
   <li>Second</li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul > li {
 width: 100px;
}
```

will apply style on both "li" as they both are child of "ul".

In your case you need to apply css on direct element. For that purpose you don't need to use child combinator.

Also you are making of CSS Pseudo classes. This classes can be directly apply to element. 
Eg.
 #mycustomid:hover
.mycustomclass:hover
elementname:hover

Check attached jsfiddle code.

http://jsfiddle.net/zgjx7ymr/

Answer (score 1):

There is no child `table` elements under the class `custom`. Try like this.

```
table.custom:hover
{
 cursor:wait;  
}
```